# Detect partial email pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am writing an unsubscribe option of email newsletters.

I have to detect emails of following format:

```
<0 or more alphanumeric letter/digit only>, then one <@> character, then <1 or more alphanumeric letter/digit>, then a <.> character, then <at least 2 alphanumeric letter/digits>
```

I need "zero" or more alphanumeric character before @ character and not "one" or more because sometimes I want to unsubscribe whole domain names, so in that case the pattern to match is `@example.com`, and I also want to detect full email, it starts with an alphanumeric character.

How can I write the code to detect?

I take the email from url as `$_GET['email']`

For example url will be:

```
http://www.example.com/php/unsubscribe.php?email=@example.com
http://www.example.com/php/unsubscribe.php?email=@example.co
http://www.example.com/php/unsubscribe.php?email=abc@example.co
```

Comment: use php filter function filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Comment: Why do you even care about this? If you want to unsubscribe the email address, it's either in the system or it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the Regex then simply reads

```
/@.+\.[^\.]{2,}$/
```

EDIT: I used `.*` and `[^\.]` even though the OP asked for "alphanumeric letter/digit" - however, valid E-Mail addresses include stuff like dashes, underscores etc... Completely matching ALL valid email adresses is incredibly complex! (see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: I used your regex in this code, but it does not work: <?php
if (preg_match("/@.*+\.[^\.]{2,}$/", "abc@mail.com", $matches))
 {
  echo "Match was found <br />";
  echo $matches[0];
}
?>

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'does not work'? Note that my regex will not match the whole email address, it will only check whether or not it is vald (add `.*` before `@` to match the whole address)

Comment: whops there also was a typo; fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex.

```
[A-Za-z0-9]*@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qM2pT8/3)

`[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}` matches two or more alphanumeric characters. You could specify the character range inside `{}` paranthesis.